# How to share an Authorize method for an Admin Role and Anonymous Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute, asp.net-roles

I'm working in `WebAPI`. I'm having the following two methods to send the data to the respective client.

The Signature of the Method is

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public string GetMessage()
{
    return "I'm a Member of StackOverflow";
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public string GetAdminMessage()
{
    return "I'm a Member of StackOverflow since 2010";
}
```

Kindly assist me how to club these two methods in a single method, based on role it should return the data.

Expected Skeletal Structure should be

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize ???]
public string GetMessage()
{
    return "I'm a Member of StackOverflow" + (Roles == Admin) ? "since 2010" : String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `if (this.User.IsInRole("Admin")) { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: @haim770 - What's the structure of Authorize attribute do I need to give `[Authorize ???]`

Comment: Just apply `[Authorize]` with no parameter. It will make sure only authorized users can access the action (regardless of their roles). Then you imperatively check their roles using the `if ...`

Comment: @haim770 - Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

you can pas roles as separate with comma `[Authorize(Roles="role1,role2")]`. but you dont need send roles on this case. Because there is no role of anonymous.

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetMessage()
{
    return "I'm a Member of StackOverflow" + User != null && User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "since 2010" : String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Authorize]` for both Specific Role and Anonymous Role, Moreover use the role based validation within the method not in attribute level.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public string GetMessage()
{
    return "I'm a Member of StackOverflow" + 
        ((this.User != null) && (this.User.IsInRole("Admin"))) 
            ? "since 2010" : String.Empty;
}
```